# How can you link a Facebook event to a page after it has been created?

Tags: facebook

I have a Facebook page for some organizations that do events,
but on occasion, I create an event as my own user.

I'd like to be able to make the page the owner of the event.

Is there a method to do this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no method to do this. Once the event is created there is no way to relink it to an event owner.